# How to add rows to slice in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe `df` with some data. And I also have a Slice `selection` made with the condition `cond_1`.

```
    def cond1(row):
        if some_condition_1:
            return True
        return False

    def cond2(row):
        if some_condition_2:
            return True
        return False

    selection = df[df.apply(cond1, axis=1)]

    # Some logic here
    #...
    #
    # Later:
```

But I need to append some data using other condition `cond2`
So can I just extend `selection` using `cond2` or maybe I should make `selection2` and then join them?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
...

selection1 = dataframe based on some condition
selection2 = dataframe based on some condition

selection1 = selection1[selection1.apply(cond1, axis=1)]
selection2 = selection2[selection2.apply(cond2, axis=1)]

pd.concat([selection1, selection2])
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work like this because there some time between `cond1` and `cond2` filtering and `cond1` can't be calculated when we need to make `cond2`

Comment: @GhostKU then you need to have seperate data in separate df. Because when you will call your cond2(), all the rows will be checked and same for cond1(). So if for some data either of these can't be calculated then it will throw error. So good way it to seperate data first, then call function individually and then merge them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```py
ind_cond1 = df.apply(cond1, axis=1)
ind_cond2 = df.apply(cond2, axis=1)

## if you want to slice df which matches either of the condition
or_cond = ind_cond1 | ind_cond2
df[or_cond]

## if you want to slice df which matches both condition
and_cond = ind_cond1 & ind_cond2
df[and_cond]

## you can also use other logical operation like xor, not etc
```